# Angular 5- Browser tab gets frozen when loading over 100k data

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 5 and facing an performance issue.

I had implemented input field with autosuggestions. For this autosuggestion we had nearly 100k data. If we don't restrict the record to certain number the browser gets frozen.

```
<td>
<input type="text" placeholder="Title" auto-complete [source]="titleList"
    value-property-name="id" display-property-name="name" 
    [list-formatter]="autocompleteListFormatter"
    (valueChanged)="onSelected1(ruleItem, 'title')"
    [(ngModel)]="ruleItem.titleSysId" class="disableInputClass"
    [disabled]="ruleItem.groupfromgroupFlag">
</td>
```

Comment: please provide the error which you are getting or the code which you tried?

Comment: are you using any library to achieve this

Comment: we are listing the suggestions using ng2-auto-complete library

Comment: <td><input type="text" placeholder="Title" auto-complete
[source]="titleList" value-property-name="id" 
display-property-name="name" 
[list-formatter]="autocompleteListFormatter"
(valueChanged)="onSelected1(ruleItem, 'title')"
[(ngModel)]="ruleItem.titleSysId" class="disableInputClass"      [disabled]="ruleItem.groupfromgroupFlag"></td>

Comment: use pagination and optimize query. You playing with 1lakh records which slow down your performance and hang browser.

Answer (score 0):

After fetching data from the server for autosuggestion.
Use Array filter splice method. This makes sure that even if the result data is too many then only part of it will be rendered this may not solve your performance issue completely but it will help somewhat.

For example

```
    this.http.get("example.com")
        .subscribe(data:[] => { 
        this.allData = data;
        this.mydataArray = this.allData.splice(0,100);
    })
```

`
Now Render the myDataArray only for performance boost.

Another thing you can do is to **have pagination on the server side and return only 100 records first then after return next 100 records save browser from the bottleneck.**

Comment: thanks shri for your quick response. is it possible to add infinite scroll to the suggestion?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can do infinite scrolling.